# Appending a WooCommerce Button Link with a PHP Variable

Tags: php, woocommerce

[image]

Hi on the Woocommerce shop page I would like to modify the button link, to append it with a php variable and value.

Here is the button code:

```
<a href="https://example.com/product/polo-shirt/" data-quantity="1" class="button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button" data-product_id="41" data-product_sku="" aria-label="Add to cart: “Polo Shirt”" aria-describedby="" rel="nofollow">Select options</a>
```

I would like to append the URL to example:  https://example.com/product/polo-shirt/?var=value

Is there a Woocommerce filter hook I can use ?  I cannot find one. If not what would be the best solution.

Comment: The hook is `woocommerce_loop_product_link`… located in [here](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/8.6/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-template-functions.php#L1210)

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason the hook will not execute. To make sure, I added an exit clause in the hook to test if it is being executed.

Comment: Maybe because of your theme own customizations… You need to ask in your theme support, what hook you can use to replace  `woocommerce_loop_product_link`…

Comment: Yes that is what I was thinking, or perhaps a woocommerce plugin installed.